# Add credentials to access REST controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a web service with several controllers. I need to add authentication for only one of them. The rest should remain without authentication. Note that I just need to add the username and password in the request header. No login form. I am using spring boot application.

Code i tried:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("{noop}pass").roles("ADMIN");

}

// Secure the endpoints with HTTP Basic authentication
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            //HTTP Basic authentication
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/myController").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable();
}
```

However it is not requesting a user and password. If i remove {noop} it does but throws an exception of  invalid password encoder

Comment: Great, sounds like you have some requirements to implement. However, you haven't posted a question (just the requirements). Please clarify what question you exactly have and post any relevant code into the question itself. For example, right now I'm unsure whether you're having issues with differentiating between those controllers, or with the type of authentication (using a request header) and exactly what issue you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem using the following code:

@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
public static String ROLE_NAME = "ROLENAME";

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder("key", 10000, 128))
            .withUser("userName").password("encryptedPassword").roles(ROLE_NAME);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/securedPath").hasRole(ROLE_NAME)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable();
}

}
```

You can configure the encrypted password and apply any changes needed to this code. Main target is to secure only one rest API with path securedPath, the given username and password can be used with or without encryption. For my example I used encrypted password and I added it to a configuration file. This class will automatically decrypt the password and use it. No UI needed as the browser automatically pop up a login form.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase you are looking for is `Method level Security in Spring`. Searching on google with this term might take you to what you need. If not you will have to be more specific with your requirement.